# Invalid ClientID/ClientSecret from FuelSDK Exacttarget api

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, fuel-sdk, python

I'm getting email actions (opens, clicks, sent) via Exacttarget python Fuel SDK but after a while I'm getting the following error on some occasions:

```
File "../FuelSDK/client.py", line 201, in refresh_token
raise Exception('Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided: ' + repr(r.json()))

Exception: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided: {u'errorcode': 0, u'message': u'Internal Server Error', u'documentation': u'https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/500'}
```

I'm pulling a large amount of actions, and I'm getting the error every so often. When my app crashes due to the error, I rerun the app and I'm able to pull actions again. After a certain amount of time, I get the error again, and the process repeats.

Can anyone give me insights into this error? I know my ClientID and ClientSecret are correct since my app does pull actions, could the error be a result of going over the api request limit (which I believe is 50,000 request per day) ?

Comment: Looks like a python client library issue. Open an issue on github.

Answer (score 1):

I also get this error every so often. I suspect it's due to the validation process timing out, and throwing an unhelpful error message. I'm using a PHP library, however.